# REST GET using SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, xml

I've been testing an outgoing REST GET request (towards the other world, not towards SharePoint).

When I'm using this code in **pure JavaScript/HTML** it works just fine. But when using it in my SharePoint app I'm receiving a JavaScript runtime error:

> NetworkError at client.send(null);

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
var url = "https://test.com/example/something/1";

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open("GET", url, false);

client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.setRequestHeader("theplatform", "default");
client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic keyofsomethingvalue%");

client.send(null);     

if (client.status == 200)
    alert("The request succeeded!\n\nThe response representation was:\n\n" + client.responseText)
else
    alert("The request did not succeed!\n\nThe response status was: " + client.status + " " + client.statusText + ".");
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Comment: This is more of a javascript question than a SharePoint one.

Comment: @Akhoy well it is sharepoint related, as when I'm using this code in pure javascript/html it works just fine, but when using sharepoint - nope?

Comment: Right, didn't know that. You should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

CSOM and the REST API include the WebProxy for these operations.

[Query a remote service using the web proxy in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895.aspx)

Code sample:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../_api/SP.WebProxy.invoke",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(
        {
            "requestInfo": {
                "__metadata": { "type": "SP.WebRequestInfo" },
                "Url": url,
                "Method": "GET",
                "Headers": {
                    "results": [{
                        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.KeyValue" },
                        "Key": "Accept",
                        "Value": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Note 1: You need to register the target domain as a remote endpoint in the app manifest.

Note 2: Response size must not exceed 200 Kb.

Comment: This works, I've just got a small problem 'Access to http://example.com is denied. SharePoint is currently configured to block intranet calls.', do you have any further tips? :)

Comment: Why would you say my next question was a duplicate of this question?

Comment: Now this is my next question.

Comment: Don't update your question like that. I've rolled it back to the previous state so that it matches up with the response. If you are having a problem, open a new question with the specifics.

Comment: @EricAlexander he had actually opened a new question but it was marked as duplicate. :)

Comment: I marked as duplicate. I thought that we weren't supposed to open a new question. My apologies if that was not the case.